# Serial column takes up disproportional amount of space in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, indexing, primary-key, auto-increment

I would like to create an auto-incrementing `id` column that is **not a primary key** in a PostgreSQL table.  The table is currently just over 200M rows and contains 14 columns.

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_total_relation_size('mytable'));
```

The above query reveals that `mytable` takes up **57 GB** on disk.  I currently have 30 GB free space remaining on disk after checking with `df -h` (on Ubuntu 20.04)

What I don't understand is why, after trying to create a `SERIAL` column, I completely run out of disk space - the query ends up never finishing.  I run the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN id SERIAL;
```

and then see how gradually, my disk space runs out until there is nothing left and the query fails. I am no database expert but it does not make sense. Why would a simple serialized column take up more than half of the space of the table itself, especially when it is not a primary key and therefore has no index?  Is there a known workaround to creating such an auto-incrementing id column?

Comment: Completely unrelated to your space problem, but: using serial [is discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don't_Do_This#Don.27t_use_serial) in favor of standard compliant `identity` columns

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful formation, but how should I implement an identity column to reach my goal?

Comment: You are running out of space because `SERIAL` is a basically a macro that does this [Serial](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL). The result is a rewrite of the table. To come up a solution we need to know what you want achieve with new column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a proof of concept:

```
create table id_test(pk_fld integer primary key generated always as identity);
--FYI, in Postgres 14+ the overriding system value won't be needed.
--That is a hack around a bug in 13-
insert into id_test overriding system value values (default), (default);
select * from id_test;
 pk_fld 
--------
      1
      2
alter table id_test add column id_fld integer ;
update id_test set id_fld = 0;
alter table id_test alter COLUMN id_fld set not null;
alter table id_test alter COLUMN id_fld add generated always as identity;
update id_test set id_fld = default;
select * from id_test;
pk_fld | id_fld 
--------+--------
      1 |      1
      2 |      2
```

Basically this breaks the process down into steps. Obviously this is just a toy table and not representative of your setup. I would try it on test table that is a subset of you actual table to see what happens to disk space consumption. It would not hurt to use `VACUUM` after the updates to return rows to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `serial` column is adding an `integer` column with a non-constant `DEFAULT` value. This will cause PostgreSQL to rewrite the table, because the new column value has to be added to all existing rows. So PostgreSQL writes a new copy of the table and discards the old one after it is done. This will require more than double the disk space of the original table temporarily, which explains why you run out of disk space.

You can split the operation into several steps:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD id bigint;
CREATE SEQUENCE mytable_id_seq OWNED BY mytable.id;
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER id SET DEFAULT nextval('mytable_id_seq');
```

This will not rewrite the table, and it will leave the existing rows untouched. The value of `id` for these columns will be NULL.

You probably want to update the existing rows to be `NOT NULL`, but be careful: if you update them all at once, you will run out of disk space as well, because in PostgreSQL an `UPDATE` writes a complete new version of the row to the table. You'd have to update the rows in batches and run `VACUUM` between these updates.

All in all, this is rather annoying and complicated. So do yourself a favor and increase the disk space. That is the simple and best solution.